# Woocommerce custom content-product.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

This is the basic code for the template content-product.php

```
<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
    ?>


    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
    ?>

</a>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); ?>
```

The question is that I need to show much more information for every product in the main page. Here it only shows title, image, price and add to cart button. I need to be able to show, short description, attributes, custom fields, etc...

How can i accomplish this?

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you'll need to add some hooks.

Here is a reference on how to do that:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

I'd suggest making a separate plugin that adds hooks to either 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' or 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title'.

Then inside your custom functions, add the information you need.

**Or** better yet, I was looking at the [source code](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/content-product.php) for this file, and it says you can simply override the whole file by copying this file and placing it in to your theme at:  yourtheme/woocommerce/content-product.php

That way you can just make the adjustments straight to that file.

To add the short description, you will want to use the [the_excerpt()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt) function provided by wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

To add a short description I invite you to add this piece of code to the desired location:

```
?>
<p class="xxx">
<?php echo $post->post_excerpt; ?>
</p>
<?php
```

For example to add it under the title just put it under

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
```

And for the style I let you manage in css.

Excuse my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy php scripts from content-single-product.php and display them on the template content-product.php.It is better this ways as you will be able to control elements using HTML and CSS.

Comment: Woocommerce templates are self explainatory and if a user is capable of handling php then he can simply copy contents from content-single-template.Its already there. :)

Comment: Ok .. I am putting the snippet(to be included where ever you want to dispaly excerpt) of a modified content-product.php from WooCommerce to display excerpt only :- ` <div class="product-info">
     <div itemprop="description">
 <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ) ?>
</div></div>` .All the template files are getting called from Woocommerce - Single Product

Answer (score 0):

try this code. i customised the order of stuff so image is at the bottom rather then top but all variations will be shown. only thing i cant do is put two classes in a row rather then stacked just to save space but my php is limited. if anyone could add to this to customize into a better table , id love to hear about it.

```js
    <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying product content within loops.
 *
 * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/content-product.php
 *
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.4.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product, $woocommerce_loop;

// Store loop count we're currently on
if ( empty( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] ) ) {
 $woocommerce_loop['loop'] = 0;
}

// Store column count for displaying the grid
if ( empty( $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) ) {
 $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = apply_filters( 'loop_shop_columns', 4 );
}

// Ensure visibility
if ( ! $product || ! $product->is_visible() ) {
 return;
}

// Increase loop count
$woocommerce_loop['loop']++;

// Extra post classes
$classes = array();
if ( 0 == ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] - 1 ) % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] || 1 == $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) {
 $classes[] = 'first';
}
if ( 0 == $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) {
 $classes[] = 'last';
}
?>
<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>

 <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

<?php

  /**
   * remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
                 * remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
                 * remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' ); 


 ?>

 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> 

 <?php
   
                         /**
    * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
    *
    * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
    * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
    */
   do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );          

   /**
    * woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title hook
    *
    * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
    */
   do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

   /**
    * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
    *
    * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
    * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
    */
   do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
  ?>

 </a>

 

</li>
```